# Puedo en un Checkbox si es marcado enviar 1 caso contrario enviar 0?

Tags: php, checkbox

Puedo en un Checkbox si es marcado enviar 1 caso contrario enviar 0?

De esta última manera como lo he intentado en la tabla se envia un 0, lo que necesito es que se envie un "1" si esta marcado si no que llegue "0".

Este es el código del formulario:

```html
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IE | Industrial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="container">

      <form action="insertar_acudiente.php" method="post">

        <h2>Acudiente</h2>
       <h3> <div align="center">
          <input type="hidden" name="id_alumno" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>">
          <label>Alumno</label><input type="text" name= "nombre_alumno" value="<?php echo $alumnos['nombres']; ?>" readonly="readonly"><br>
        </div></h3>
        <img src="images/actualizar.fw.png">

        <label>Papá</label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="">
        <label>Mamá</label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="">
        <label>Abuelo</label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="">
        <label>Abuela</label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" value="">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="hermanos" placeholder="Total hermanos">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="otros" placeholder="Otros">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="matriculo" placeholder="Quien matriculo">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="totalconvive" placeholder="Total con quien vive">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="aportes" placeholder="Aportes">

        <input type="submit" value="REGISTRAR">
        <?php
      endforeach
      ?>
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Este es el Codigo PHP que inserta a la base de datos:

```
<?php

    //$id=($_GET['id']);

    NuevoAcudiente($_POST['id_alumno'], $_POST['nombre_alumno'], $_POST['checkbox'], $_POST['checkbox'], $_POST['checkbox'], $_POST['checkbox'], $_POST['hermanos'], $_POST['otros'], $_POST['matriculo'], $_POST['totalconvive'], $_POST['aportes']);

    function NuevoAcudiente($id, $nombre_alumno, $papa, $mama, $abuelo, $abuela, $hermanos, $otros, $matriculo, $totalconvive, $aportes)
    {
        include 'conexion.php';
        $checkbox = 0;
        if(($_POST['checkbox1'] != "")){
            $checkbox = 1;
        }
```

Codigo SQL

```
$sentencia="INSERT INTO tbl_acudiente (id_alumno, nombre_alumno, papa, mama, abuelo, abuela, hermanos, otros, matriculo, totalconvive, aportes) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$nombre_alumno."', '".$checkbox."', '".$checkbox."', '".$checkbox."', '".$checkbox."', '".$hermanos."', '".$otros."', '".$matriculo."', '".$totalconvive."','".$aportes."')";
                    $mbd->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al ingresar los datos".mysqli_error($conexion));


    }
?>
```

Comment: No se logra entender tu programación, ese grupo de checbox tendría que tener el mismo `name` y lo que los diferencia es el `value` que no estás poniendo, en tu codigo PHP estás poniendo `$_POST['checkbox'], $_POST['checkbox'],...`, cuando debería ser `$_POST['checkbox1'],$_POST['checkbox2']` o me equivoco?, deberías de plantear mejor tu código porque no se entiende qué es lo que deseas hacer.

Answer (score 1):

al enviar el formulario solo te manda los campos checkbox marcados. 
en tu código backend deberás verificar si esta definida la variable(names de checkbox)

ejemplo

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox1']))//revisa si esta definido tu variable, en este caso si tu checkbox esta marcado la variable esta definida 
  //realizas tus operaciones, si entra en esta condición puedes acceder al valor de tu variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de los operadores ternarios para definir uno u otro valor, te dejo este ejemplo sobre cómo hacerlo y así harás con cada checkbox.

```
$checkbox1 = (isset($_POST["checkbox1"])) ? '1' : '0';
$checkbox2 = (isset($_POST["checkbox2"])) ? '1' : '0';
//.... etc ......
```

**Sugerencia:** Veo que en tu código PHP cuando recibes los `checkbox`, todos los estás obteniendo como `$_POST["checkbox"]` y veo que en el HTML el name de cada `checkbox` va con un número, quizá eso te esté generando problemas.